# How to type french accents with a US Apple keyboard in Windows 7 (EN) with Boot Camp

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard

Everything's in the question. I have an iMac running Snow Leopard with a US Apple keyboard, and I've installed Windows 7 (english) with boot camp. I need to be able to type French accents but I don't really anyway to do it.
I tried the way I did on Snow Leopard with the ALT + E and E for instance to make an e acute and even the Windows way with ALT + 1 3 0 but no luck.

Any of you have something to suggest to me?

Cheers,
Nicolas.

Comment: What's your Windows keyboard layout? The fact that some glyph is or isn't printed on a plastic part means nothing to your operating system.

Comment: French Accents... US Apple keyboard... Windows 7 and Boot camp? Huh... that's F**kin' a lot! wow! :)

Comment: @Daniel: US keyboard as described in my message, but not a "standard" one, the US keyboard provided with an iMac by Apple. I do know but I hoped the Apple or Windows keyboard combinations would woek but none of them did as I explained before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alt codes only work on the numeric keypad, which you probably lack.

Try [the international keyboard](http://french.about.com/od/writing/ss/typeaccents_2.htm). I use the same thing for German umlauts in my virtual machines. Only downside is, it drives me crazy if all I want to do is type double quotation marks.

Another option is creating a custom keyboard layout using [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665). I used that in 2008(ish) when I connected my wired UK Apple keyboard to a Windows machine and had to be able to type umlauts. It was quite easy to define `Alt-u` as `ü` etc. It can even load one of the existing layouts you can use as a base to make your (few) modifications.

Comment: Both of your solutions sound good, I'll give them a try and keep you updated, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Then keyboard layout generator is just awesome, thanks for the tip ;)